# jQuery checkbox check and uncheck not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I am trying to find out if it is checked or unchecked with a change function. What might be the issues with below code?

```js
function onCheckChange(id){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert('checked');
  } else {
    alert('unchecked');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox id='chk' onchange='onCheckChange(this)'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$(this)` is not available in the `onCheckChange` function use `id` instead of `this`. You probably need to change the name of parameter `onCheckChange` as you are passing the event source *object* not the `id` of event source object.

You can use `$()` to convert the `DOM` object being passed to `jQuery` object to call `is()` on it

```
function onCheckChange(sourceObj){
    if ($(sourceObj).is(":checked")) {
        alert('checked');
    }
    else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the handler does not refer the checkbox. Since you are passing `this` to the method from the `onchange` handler, it refers to the dom element so you can use it to refer to the changed element like

```
<input type=checkbox id='chk' onchange='onCheckChange(this)'>
```

then

```
function onCheckChange(el){
    if ($(el).is(":checked")) {//or just el.checked
        alert('checked');
    }
    else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
}
```